# Caffe Installation: Both make and cmake fail

Tags: python, caffe, failed-installation

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7, NVIDIA Driver 367, Cuda-8.0, CudNN-5.0, GTX-1080, and I am trying to install Caffe on my system. I am currently using Tensorflow on my system with no issues. I have installed all prerequisites as advised by http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org and I believe I have chosen the right configuration (including library paths, etc.). The initial stages,

```
make all
make test
```

run with no error or warning. Then at 'make runtest' I get the following error

make: execvp: .build_release/tools/caffe permission denied

I thought this is simply a permission issue and ran it with 'sudo make runtest' and got the exact same error. I also used 'sudo su -' and ran 'make runtest' as root and the same problem persists.

Then I tried to use cmake to build Caffe and similarly

make all
make install

run with no warnings or errors but when I run 'make runtest' I get:

```
[100%] Built target proto
[100%] Built target caffe
[100%] Built target gtest
[100%] Built target test.testbin
/bin/sh: 1: /media/MainStorage/caffe-master/build/test/test.testbin:  Permission denied
make[3]: *** [src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest] Error 126
make[2]: *** [src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [runtest] Error 2
```

Running it as root did not fix the issue. I would highly appreciate any input.

Comment: Maybe try chmod 744 /media/MainStorage/caffe-master/build/test/test.testbin?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Same error! I really don't think this should be a permission error as when I run it as root I still get the same error.

Comment: I think this was asked in BVLC/caffe in github also, where I commented below: Its not clear without the log where it failed. To confirm if testbin is really created, try running it directly from command line as below - cd /media/MainStorage/caffe-master && /media/MainStorage/caffe-master/build/test/test.testbin --gtest_shuffle . Also, make sure you did not install the caffe-master folder with higher privileges. It could also be possible that CUDA is not installed properly. Above step will show the real cause.

Answer (score 0):

This post is quite old now, and I am not so sure about my answer as I am also a newbie in Linux, but I hope my comment would be useful to some other.
I got the same problem like yours on Ubuntu 14, but not on Ubuntu 16. My problem comes from the NTFS drive which I installed Caffe on. By default, Ubuntu 14 does not allow execution permission on mounted NTFS drives. If you are in a similar situation, just copy the whole Caffe folder to a ext4 drive and make again.

P/S: there seem to be some fix available for NTFS on Ubuntu 14, but I did not try :)